# Pylons redirect me on domain instead of subdomain

Tags: pylons

When I go to `http:// sub.domain.com` where is my Pylons project, application should redirect me on `http:// sub.domain.com/login?redirect=/`, but it's redirecting me on `http:// domain.com/login?redirect=/`

All redirections are to http:// domain.com/[rest of url]/ instead of http:// sub.domain.com/[rest of url]/ but project is under http:// sub.domain.com.

No-redirect requests works fine.

I use Pylons 1.0, mod_wsgi and Apache with virtual hosts.

Comment: You should put your answer in an answer rather than editing the question and then uprank it. Otherwise, this question stays in the "Unanswered" list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved. Just set map.sub_domains = False